# Codeigniter 2 forms on one page, validation_errors problem

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

On one of my websites I have 2 forms on one page, I am having a problem, with `validation_errors();` basically what is happening, is for one of the forms I am checking for errors and if there are any errors I am doing some styling to turn the labels red, how the other form just display errors using `echo validation_errors();`. When I submit the form that does not display errors just error styling the validation errors are show in the form. How can I stop this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your question is a bit hard to read, but if I understand correctly - you're having trouble validating 2 separate forms from one controller, or issues dealing with errors from different forms using `validation_errors()` which afaik prints ALL errors:

Before running validation, check for the existence of either a hidden field, a field that is unique to the form, or you can check the value of the particular submit button.

```
<form>
<input type="hidden" name="form1" value="whatever">
<input name="form1_email" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit Form 1" />
</form>
```

Then you can use any of these methods to check which form was submitted (This example checks if "form1" was submitted):

```
<?php
// Choose one:
if ($this->input->post('form1')): // check the hidden input
if ($this->input->post('form1_email')): // OR check a unique value
if ($this->input->post('submit') == 'Submit Form 1'): // OR check the submit button value

    if ($this->form_validation->run()):

        // process form

    else:
            // Create a variable with errors assigned to form 1
            // Make sure to pass this to your view
            $data['form1_errors'] = validation_errors();
    endif;

endif;
// Do same for form 2
```

Then in your view, instead of using `validation_errors()` you would use:

```
if (isset($form1_errors)) echo $form1_errors; // Print only form1's errors
```

If this doesn't help let me know, and clarify your question by posting your code.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was divide both forms. The view would be like

```
    <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
    <?php echo form_open('form1'); ?>
    <form id="form1" action="some_action">
    //Inputs
    </form> 
    <?php echo form_open('form2'); ?>
    <form id="form2" action="other_action">
    //Inputs
    </form>
```

Now, in the controller you can have two different functions for each validation:

```
    //Controller
    function some_action(){
    //validate form and code
    } 

    function other_action(){
    //validate form2 and code
    }
```

Now, all validation messages will appear in the same place but will only show the messages of each form. Hope that helps