# multiple form validation codeigniter conflict

Tags: php, codeigniter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Codeigniter 2 forms on one page, validation_errors problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802729/codeigniter-2-forms-on-one-page-validation-errors-problem)

I have 2 forms in my page. I need to validate them 1 at a time but I think there is a conflict. Here take a look:

[image]

when I submit either of the form, both of them show the same error message

I use `validation_errors()` to display the messages. How can I validate the form 1 at a time?

Here is the code

```
public function update_user_info(){ 
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("firstname","First Name","required");     
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("lastname","Last Name","required"); 
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("middlename","Middle Name","required"); 
    if($this->form_validation->run()===false){ 
        //wrong 
    } 
    else { //correct } 
}
```

Comment: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802729/codeigniter-2-forms-on-one-page-validation-errors-problem`

Comment: public function update_user_info(){
  $this->form_validation->set_rules("firstname","First Name","required");
  $this->form_validation->set_rules("lastname","Last Name","required");
  $this->form_validation->set_rules("middlename","Middle Name","required");

  if($this->form_validation->run()===false){
   //wrong
  }else{
   //correct
  }
 }

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just encountered the issue.
My solution is:

1.First set the first submit button name = 'update_info'

2.Secondly set the second submit button name = 'change_password'

3.Last change your update_user_info().

```
public function update_user_info(){ 
    if (isset ($_POST['update_info'])) {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("firstname","First Name","required");     
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("lastname","Last Name","required"); 
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("middlename","Middle Name","required"); 
        if($this->form_validation->run()===false){ 
            //wrong 
        } 
        else { //correct }             
    }
    else if (isset ($_POST['change_password'])){
        form_validation of your change password
    }
```

I think this is the easiest way to fix your issue.

Good luck.

Answer (score 5):

You can take one hidden input for each form

```
First Form:
<input type="hidden" name="form" value="form1" />

Second Form:
<input type="hidden" name="form" value="form2" />
```

In your controller, you can set array of rules for each form

```
$config['form1'] = array(
               array(
                     'field'   => 'username', 
                     'label'   => 'Username', 
                     'rules'   => 'required'
                  ),
               array(
                     'field'   => 'password', 
                     'label'   => 'Password', 
                     'rules'   => 'required'
                  ),
            );

$config['form2'] = array(
               array(
                     'field'   => 'email', 
                     'label'   => 'Email', 
                     'rules'   => 'required'
                  ),
            );

Now check which hidden field posted

$form = $this->input->post('form')


Now you can set rules as below

$this->form_validation->set_rules($config[$form]);

if ($this->form_validation->run()):

    // process form

else:
        $data[$form.'_errors'] = validation_errors();
endif;
```

Now in your view file

```
if (isset($form1_errors)) echo $form1_errors;
if (isset($form2_errors)) echo $form2_errors;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have different validation errors for each form you can check the output from `validation_errors`.

As far as I can see `validation_errors` only allows you to change the delimiters of errors and nothing else. However, you can try showing individual form errors like so: `<?php echo form_error('username'); ?>`