# Codeigniter multi forms on one page validation errors

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have two forms in my page. when I submit either of the form, both of them show the same validation error message. I used

```
if (isset ($_POST['click_cus_button']))
```

to check what button is licked in the from seems it does not work for me.

Can anyone tell me why this bit of code isn't working?

**this is my controller (admin.php)**

```
function add_users_data()
{

    if (isset ($_POST['click_cus_button']))// click_cus_button is set load this validation errors
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('cus_name', 'Name', 'trim|required|min_length[5]');
        // validate name
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('cus_email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
        // validate email
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('cus_phone', 'Phone Number', 'trim|required|min_length[10]|max_length[10]');
        // validate phone number
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('cus_password', 'Password', 'required|matches[cus_passconf]');
        // validate password
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('cus_passconf', 'Retype Password', 'required');
        // validate password
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)// if from validation failed load following pages from views
        {

            $this->load->view('admin/admin_add_users.php');

        }
        else // if from validation success load following pages from views
        {
            $data = array(
                'cus_name' => $this->input->post('cus_name'),
                'cus_email' => $this->input->post('cus_email'),
                'cus_mobile' => $this->input->post('cus_mobile'),
                'cus_phone' => $this->input->post('cus_phone'),
                'cus_status' => $this->input->post('cus_status')
                //'database_field' => $this->input->post('text_box_name')
            );
            $this->mod_users->add_record($data);//add a comment
            $data['result']="Customer Added Successfully ";
            $this->load->view('admin/admin_add_users.php',$data);

        }
    }
    else if (isset ($_POST['click_oper_button']))// click_oper_button is set load this validation errors
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('oper_firstname', 'Name', 'trim|required|min_length[5]');
        // validate name
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('oper_lastname', 'Name', 'trim|required|min_length[5]');
        // validate name
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)// if from validation failed load following pages from views
        {

            $this->load->view('admin/admin_add_users.php');

        }
        else // if from validation success load following pages from views
        {

            $data['result']="Customer Added Successfully ";
            $this->load->view('admin/admin_add_users.php',$data);

        }
    }
}
```

**this is my View (admin_add_users.php)**

*I removed some fields to make the code shorter in the view*

```
 <?php  echo form_open('admin/add_users_data')   ?><!-- start of the form -->
    <div class="span8">
        <div style="padding-bottom:11px;">
            <div class="div add_cus box"><!-- start of the add customer add form -->
                <?php  echo validation_errors('<div class="notice marker-on-bottom bg-darkRed fg-white" id="bottom_form_error">', '</div>'); ?>
                <?php

                if(isset($result))
                {
                    echo '<div class="notice marker-on-bottom  bg-green fg-white">'.$result.'</div>';
                }

                ?>
                <!-- Display Validation error massages  -->
                <feildset>
                    <legend><i class="icon-user-2 on-right on-left"></i><strong>Add Customer</strong></legend>

                    <input name='cus_status' type='hidden' value='disabled'/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Add Customer" class="info" name="click_cus_button">
                </feildset>
            </div><!-- END of the add customer add form -->
        </div>
        <div class="div add_oper box"><!-- start of the add Operator add form -->
            <?php  echo validation_errors('<div class="notice marker-on-bottom bg-darkRed fg-white" id="bottom_form_error">', '</div>'); ?>
            <?php

            if(isset($result))
            {
                echo '<div class="notice marker-on-bottom  bg-green fg-white">'.$result.'</div>';
            }

            ?>
            <feildset>
                <legend><i class="icon-user on-right on-left"></i><strong>Add Operator</strong></legend>
                <h6>*All fields marked are required</h6>
                <lable>Name*</lable><br>
                <div class="input-control text size6" data-role="input-control">
                    <input type="text" name="oper_firstname" placeholder="First Name">
                </div>
                <div class="input-control text size6" data-role="input-control">
                    <input type="text" name="oper_lastname" placeholder="Last Name">
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="input-control radio default-style" data-role="input-control">
                    <label>
                        Gender*<br>
                        <input type="radio" checked="" name="oper_gender">
                        <span class="check"></span>
                        Male
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-control radio default-style" data-role="input-control">
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="oper_gender">
                        <span class="check"></span>
                        Female
                    </label>
                </div>
                <br>
                <lable>Date of Birth*</lable>
                <div class="input-control text" data-role="input-control">
                    <input id="datepicker" name="oper_dob" type="text">
                </div>
                <lable>Address*</lable><br>
                <div class="input-control text size1" data-role="input-control">
                    <input type="text" name="oper_add_no" placeholder="No">
                </div>

                <input type="submit" value="Add Operator" class="info" name="click_oper_button">
            </feildset>                
        </div><!-- END of the add Operator add form -->
        <div class="div add_admin">
            RadioButton 3 Selected
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php  echo form_close(); ?><!-- END of the form -->
```

Comment: What is the error message ?

Comment: no error message both of them show the same validation error message

Comment: What's the validation error message?

Comment: The Name field is required.
The Email field is required.
The Phone Number field is required.
The Password field is required.
The Retype Password field is required.------------ this is for the form Add Customer

Comment: The Name field is required.
The Name field is required.------------ this is for the form Add Operator –

Comment: because they are both part of the same form it will submit both buttons at the same time so it will only ever process `if (isset ($_POST['click_cus_button']))`. You can either use 2 separate forms so that the 2 button names won't appear in the form submission. Or use some JS trickery to override the form submit and change a value of a hidden field based on on the button you click.

Comment: mic i am trying to do this -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795818/multiple-form-validation-codeigniter-conflict/12798451#12798451 but it is not working for me