# CodeIgniter - Two Forms, One Page

Tags: forms, codeigniter, controller

I'm having a fundamental problem in understanding the concept of MVC and displaying more than one form at a time. I've tried a variety of methods but I'm still stuck - and that's because I don't think I'm understanding CI and MVC correctly.

I tried using 2 different views for the two different forms. Didn't work. I tried using one function per form in my controller. That didn't work either. I don't know what to do.

Should I be doing this;

1. Create a controller and have an index() function in it.
2. Build up my form elements for each form within this index()
3. Create 1 view that displays both forms and call it from within index()
4. Use form_open to direct the submit action to another function - call it validate()
5. Validate everything that comes in, send back errors
6. Somehow, and this is the main bit I don't get, complete an action if the form has been filled in correctly.

6 Is my biggest problem. Don't know how to do that. For example, on successful completion of the form I want my user to have created a directory at a chosen location - so I'm using mkdir() - so do I need an if statement within the validate() function or what??

***UPDATE***

Here is the code I have created so far;

Controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

// Forms CodeIgniter controller
class Admin extends CI_Controller {

```
// Controller constructor
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    // Load form helper required to validate forms
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $this->load->library('form_validation');        
}

//*************************************************//

// Prepare data for the view to output the forms
public function index()
{

    //*****************************************************//
    //returns a drop down list of radio buttons, one for each directory
    $map_one = $this->recursive_model->iterate_add_folder_names();
    $data['folder_list_add'] = $map_one;    
    //****************************************************//
    //*****************************************************//
    //also returns a drop down list of radio buttons (slightly different), one for each directory
    $map_two = $this->recursive_model->iterate_folder_names();
    $data['folder_list_select'] = $map_two; 
    //****************************************************//

    //load the views and the forms
    $this->load->view('templates/header.php');
    $this->load->view('admin/add_new_folder.php', $data);
    $this->load->view('admin/add_new_file.php', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/small_footer.php');
}

//*************************************************//

//function if adding a new directory to the current structure
public function add_folder()
{
    //need to select a directory for it to go under
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('new_folder', 'New Folder', 'required');
    //and name the new directory
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('new_folder_name', 'New Folder Name', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
    {
        $this->index();
    }
    else
    {   
        if($this->input->post())
        {
            $new_folder = $this->input->post('new_folder');
            $new_folder_name = $this->input->post('new_folder_name');
            $folder_path = "/var/www/html/mike/content".$new_folder."/".$new_folder_name;
            mkdir($folder_path, 0777);
            $this->index();
        }
    }

}

//*************************************************//

public function add_file()
{

    //folder location and name of file
    $folder_name = $this->input->post('folder_name');
    $new_folder_name = $this->input->post('file_name');

    //validation rules
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('folder_name', 'Folder Name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('file_name', 'File Name', 'required');

    //if there is an error with validation
    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
    {
        //gets stuck here every time when trying to upload a new folder :(
        $this->index();
    }
    //if there is not an error with validation
    else
    {   
        //$folder_name will be something like "http://www.example.com/publications/people/reports"
        $config['upload_path'] = $folder_name;
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|html|pdf|xls';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        //if file cannot be loaded (due to $config perhaps?)
        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $this->index();
        }
        else
        {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            $this->index();
        }

    }   

}

//*************************************************//
```

}

Here is one view (add_new_file.php);

```
<div id="container">

<h1>Upload A File/Publication</h1>

<div id="body">

<?php //echo $error;?>

<?php echo form_open_multipart('admin/add_file');?>

<?php echo $folder_list_select; ?>   &nbsp;&nbsp; 
<input type="file" name="file_name" size="20" />   &nbsp;&nbsp; 
<input type="submit" value="upload" />

</form>

</div>
```

Here is the other (add_new_folder.php)

```
div id="container">

<h1>Add A New Folder</h1>

<div id="body">

<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

<?php echo form_open('admin/add_folder');?>

<?php echo $folder_list_add; ?>   &nbsp;&nbsp; 
New Folder Name: <input type="text" name="new_folder_name">   &nbsp;&nbsp; 
<input type="submit" value="upload" />

</form>

</div>
```

I hope this helps answer this thread.

Basically, I can get the first section to work - adding a folder - but I cannot get the adding a file to work. This is because if **($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)** is always returning false. I think it might be looking at the form elements in the other form - which it shouldn't do. What am I missing?

Comment: When you say it didn't work - in what way? Did the forms not display correctly, was there some error or did it just not do what was expected? You can load the view however you like - one view, multiple views etc. You're right, in your controller, you'll likely want one function for each form's action. For your biggest issue, I'd recommend looking through [the documentation for CodeIgniter's form validation library](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html) - it explains the process of how to handle forms well.

Comment: You mentioned 2 forms. I'm assuming you've already gotten 1 form working, and you're trying to make 2 forms. Be aware that you CAN NOT nest forms. Remember to close your form tag.

Comment: Per your edit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802729/codeigniter-2-forms-on-one-page-validation-errors-problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Should I be doing this;
>   1 . Create a controller and have an index() function in it.
>   *[**let's, for the sake of conversation, call this controller*** `Users` **thx -ed]**

Sure. That's cool. You could also have a function in that Controller called `edit`, or `banana` or whatever; either way works. With using just the `index` method (function), the url might look like `http://example.com/index.php/users` whereas if you add another method to the controller like `banana`, the url might look like `http://example.com/index.php/users/banana`.

> 2 . Build up my form elements for each form within this index()

Well, typically form elements are not created in the controllers. This is where the V in MVC comes in -- stuff you view goes into a `view`.

So, one might do something like

```
// Users Controller
class Users extends CI_Controller{
    function index(){
        //index method
    }

    function banana(){
        $this->load->view('banana_view');
    }
}
```

then in `application/views/banana_view.php`, you create your form. When you visit `http://example.com/users/banana`, you will see the form you created in `banana_view.php`.

> 3 . Create 1 view that displays both forms and call it from within index()

Sure, that'd work just fine. But remember that each `<form></form>` needs its own `<input type="submit" name="Lets GO">` inside and thusly needs somewhere to send each forms data. This is the `action=""`. You can leave it out, but beware that it will then send the form to whatever page you are currently on (in our case here, `http://example.com/index.php/users/banana`), so you have to have something in the `banana()` method to handle the form data. But, typically, it will be set via `form_open()`. Something like `form_open('index.php/users/eat_banana');` will generate `<form action="index.php/users/eat_banana"...`

> 4 . Use form_open to direct the submit action to another function - call it validate()

Just don't call it `late_for_dinner`. But seriously, `validate` is a bit broad -- validate what? Validate why? As to *validation*, https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html. But you should cross that bridge after you grok the fundamentals of CodeIgniter (won't take long).

> 5 . Validate everything that comes in, send back errors

See last question.

> 6 . Somehow, and this is the main bit I don't get, complete an action if the form has been filled in correctly.

Many times people will display a success message

```
class Users extends CI_Controller{

    function index(){
        //index method
    }

    function banana(){
        $this->load->view('banana_view');
    }

    // assuming form_open('index.php/users/eat_banana'); in banana_view
    function eat_banana(){
        //make sure that this is a POST
        if($this->input->post()){
            // do things with the data
            // typically it gets saved to a database
            // via a model (the M in MVC)
            // http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html

            if($saved_to_db){
                // set message to send to the view
                $data['message'] = "Everything went OK";
            }else{
                $data['message'] = "but who was database? data didn't save :(";
            }
            // load the view and send the data
            $this->load->view('eat_banana', $data);
        }
     }
```

`application/views/eat_banana.php`:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
 <div>
     <b>Form submitted.</b><br />
     The message is: <?php echo $message; ?>
 </div>
 </html>
```

other times, one might instead prefer to redirect

```
class Users extends CI_Controller{

    function index(){
        //index method
    }

    function banana(){
        $this->load->view('banana_view');
    }

    // assuming form_open('index.php/users/eat_banana'); in banana_view
    function eat_banana(){
        //make sure that this is a POST
        if($this->input->post()){
            // do things with the data             
            if($saved_to_db){
                // just send them to the homepage
                redirect('/');
            }else{
                // send them back to the form
                redirect('index.php/users/banana');
            }
        }
     }
```

So,

**M** is for model. Models are used to talk to the database.

**V** is for <strike>Vend</strike> view. Views render the text, forms, pictures, gifs, whatever to the screen. That's the idea anyway. There's nothing stopping you from `echo`'ing out an enormous unminimized javascript application from your controller. That would totally not be MVC tho.

**C** is for controller. Controllers call and send data to the views, receive data sent from views, take that data and send it to a model to be saved in the database (although CodeIgniter doesn't enforce this in any way either; you could if you wanted to save the data to a database directly from the controller, but this obviously defeats the MVC principal as well), retrieves data from the database and sends it to a view for display. Those are the basics anyway.