# CodeIgniter - How do I open a form inside a view?

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, view

I am trying to open uo different forms within one view so I can have things like registers etc in them.

This is an example of what I am trying to do: [image]

When I click sign up, it should pop up a window with my log in script.

Can someone tell me how this can be done and show me to some documentation/tutorials on this sort of thing?

Thanks!

Comment: can check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16821256/codeigniter-two-forms-one-page

Comment: using Fancybox or colorbox  you can

Answer (score 0):

Please mention what you did . You can call  view through jquery . hope below code will help

```
$("click on popup").click(function(event) {

    $( "#loadwhere" ).load( SITEURL+"/login", function() {})

});
```